# I want to check a condition before 2 seconds from UILocalNotification fireDate in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uilocalnotification

I set UILocalnotification for specfic time, it is working perfectly. But i want to check one condition before 2 secs from firedate. I created the notification like this,

```
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"See today's recommendations";
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Reminder";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

For example, i set the time at 2:00:10 pm. My Scenario is, i want to check one condition before 2 seconds from set time, like 2:00:08 pm. So, how to check the less than 2 seconds from this time.

Comment: you'll need to add another local notification for that…

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You can schedule another notification and handle if it is responded. There is no other way since your app may not be running. If you can afford a push notification, look for `silent push.`